# I have three process runnung in python, should I Thread or Multiprocess

Tags: python, multithreading

I need to run three processes in python. The first process uses deque to load a self popping array. It receives data from a separate source (the internet) at about 5 Hz and is stored in deque of about 600 elements. I do not want to skip data points. The second process uses matplotlib to display the data. I may want to plot the data every second. The third process copies the array and performs a numpy function on it. It may do this every second also. The last two may have additional delays. Note matplotlib may plot both raw data and function of data together. For python, should one use threads or multiprocessing in this type of processing?

Comment: How CPU intensive is your function? If you don't expect the anywhere near the whole CPU time to be used up, it doesn't really matter which system you use (and threading is much easier). If you need multiple cores running simultaneously to handle the load, then mutiprocessing is your only option (though beware that interprocess communication overhead might eat up all your gains).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the information you provided, I think you could use Thread for the internet data fetch and Multiprocess for the data process; but without more details on the implementation of your project and how CPU intensive the functions are it is hard to give a final answer. So you have to test until you get the best performance.

I recommend [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AZnGRKFUU0c) so you can better understand the difference between the two approaches and how the python **GIL** works.